# Are social media accounts (e.g. YouTube, Twitter, Instagram, etc.) considered assets?

Tags: assets, profitability

I thought this would be a relevant question to ask here. I saw other similar questions where it was made clear that things like websites and domains are assets and can be worth huge sums of money.

Some people buy domains and design skeleton interfaces for websites to end-buyers so people without much technical knowledge can still market, add content, and run a website.

My question concerns things also intangible; things like a YouTube account/etc. It makes sense that these things are worth money and are thus some kind of asset. I had a friend who ran a YouTube channel with close to 1 million subscribers, and took him 7 tiring years to get that many.

Anyways, he sold the channel to some big buyer worth north of 5 figures easily. The channel had over 10 million total views and over 500K monthly views, which is obviously very valuable to those who want big audiences, marketing, and etc. If a YouTube channel has a moderate amount of steady views/traffic and a high subscriber base, along with many high-quality videos, it is easy to see it as a highly-valuable asset. Some top YouTube channels can be appraised for millions of dollars and more.

There are many sites that sell/trade social media accounts, some of which consist of many tens of thousands of dollars. Overall, are social media accounts considered assets just like websites? Every account? To what degree? I'm curious as to how they can be valued, and under what conditions/etc.

I also wonder how this can work/draw the line between business/tax related concepts & just personal (like write offs, profits, buyouts/sellouts of content, like videos/photos, and promoting content, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Assets with zero value, perhaps. Unless you can prove that they have resale value. Good luck with that.

In other words, not worth spending time on.

Answer (score 0):

The buyer of such an account is likely treating it as an asset, and if they ever resell it capital gains (or loss) would be realized. I don't see why this would be any different for the person that created the account initially, except that the basis starts at $0 making the entire sale price taxable. How you figure the value of the account before the initial sale would be more difficult, but fortunately you may not ever need to know the value (for tax purposes) until you actually sell it.